# Android: (setOnItemClickListener) Difference between position and id

Tags: android, listview, position, onitemclicklistener

I´ve made quite many listeners and never really thought of it until now.

Basic Listview listener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "you clicked on: " +  position + " id: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

According to [documentary](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html):

position is: The position of the view in the adapter.

id is: The row id of the item that was clicked.

Could someone good-hearted explain the difference for me.

Thx in advance..

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

> *position* The position of the view in the adapter.
>   *id* The row id of the item that was clicked.

The **position** is the position of the view inside the parent. For your case (a `ListView`) it means the index of the row. (Starting at 0) For `ArrayAdapter` and `SimpleAdapter` **id** is the same as **position**. For a `CursorAdapter`, **id** is the row id of the table.

Related Answers:
[Practical Difference Between position and row id in onListItemClick()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965817/practical-difference-between-position-and-row-id-in-onlistitemclick/12966006#12966006)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25622142/2278598